# Drupal 7 - Content structure advice

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm pretty new to Drupal, I've done some maintenance works on some websites, but nothing very complicated.

I'm developing now a website with Drupal 7 and I would like to get some advice about the structure of my content to get what I need.

Here is the structure of my Main-menu:

```
|About us
| - item_about 1
| - item_about 2
| - item_about 3
|Contact
| - item_contact 1
| - item_contact 2
| - item_contact 3
```

In my main navigation, I have only the top level items of Main-menu (`About us` and `Contact`) without any drop down for sub items.

1. I would like to have a secondary menu (on the left) on `About us` page with sub items of `About us`. And I would like them to open inside `About us` page as a sub content, not in a new page.
   Do you see what I mean? :)
   Can I do this only with my Main-menu structure or do I need to change my content structure?
   I check the `Node Hierarchy` module, but I'm not sure to see exactly how I can use it to fit my needs.
2. On the homepage, I would like to have three blocks with Contact's sub items content (and a Read more button).
   How can I "query" like my Main-menu structure to get Contact's sub item linked page content?

Once again, is it possible with my current structure or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below the solution to get menu blocks on desired page and set target attributes for the links

- [Menu Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block)
- [Menu Attach Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block)
- [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) - allows you to set target attributes for links.

These three modules allowed you to achieve the desired one.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'll try to be more precise. I don't need a menu with drop down sub menu. yes I need a block menu on specific page, but I would like the content of links to open in a parent page (where the menu block is displayed), not in a new page.
On the home page, I would like to display an excerpt of the content of linked pages of sub item under Contact.
Hope it helps you to understand what I need!

Comment: Thanks for briefing, As you mentioned that you want to open  the links in parent page only and not in new page, then for this, use [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module, it helps you to set the target attributes for the links. I am editing my above answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your prayers is menu block module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block

With standard drupal installation when ever you make some menu you automatically get menu block for it. But it doens't have too much options.

Manu block allows you to create another block(s) out of your menu, but with more options. One of them is to select just a branch instead of whole menu tree and to select what levels of menu should be displayed in menu block you create.

If you need some more advanced block placing manipulation (what block to place where in what situation) check out on conntext module too:

https://www.drupal.org/project/context

Comment: Thanks MilanG, I'll check it